# installing a tar file

Tags: software-installation

tar -xvzf netcdf-4.3.0.tar.gz tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: Too many levels of symbolic links tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now tar: Child returned status 2 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: you may look at `http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=325284` it may be a symlink issue with gzip

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely understand why you are going to extract and install program which [is packaged in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=netcdf-bin).

Just install it with `sudo apt-get install netcdf-bin`.

Answer (score -1):

You can force gunzip to ignore the levels of symbolic links.

First `gunzip --force netcdf-4.3.0tar.gz` which will give you a file netcdf-4.3.tar. Then `tar xvf netcdf-4.3.tar` will unpack the tar file. (Before unpacking you can check with `tar tvf netcdf-4.3.tar` if the file contains absolute or relative paths).

Attention: tar overwrites without asking, if it has the permission to do so.